# Hiera only run the first match

Tags: puppet, hiera

I would like to create a default users for all servers, but in addition of this default uses, only for specific servers I want to create in addition of the default users a specifics ones.

My problem is that when I run puppet agent -t, puppet only create the users for the first match. If the server match in - node/%{::fqdn} create only the specific users but not the default ones.

in /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml I have the follow:

```
:backends:
  - yaml
:yaml:
  :datadir: "/etc/puppet/hieradata"

:hierarchy:
 - node/%{::fqdn}
 - common
```

How I can set up hiera in order to always run the common file?

Answer (score 1):

Please use hiera [hash merge](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/lookup_types.html#hash-merge). Define merge behaviour in `hiera.yaml`, possible values are `native, deep, deeper` e.g:

```
:merge_behavior: deeper
```

And than just use hiera. According to [documentation:](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/lookup_types.html#merge-behaviors)

> In a deeper hash merge, Hiera recursively merges keys and values in each source hash.

Here you have merge behaviour in [examples](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/lookup_types.html#example).

**UPDATE:**
I have setup the following simple example:

`hiera.yaml:`

```
:hierarchy:
  - apps
  - common

:merge_behavior: deeper
```

`apps.yaml:`

```
test_hash:
  abc1:
    value: apps
  abc2:
    value: apps
```

`common.yaml:`

```
test_hash:
  abc1:
    value: comm
  abc3:
    value: comm
```

`test_hash.pp`

```
class test_hash
{
  $normal_hash = hiera('test_hash')
  $hiera_hash = hiera_hash('test_hash')
  notify{ " normal: ${normal_hash}":}
  notify{ " hiera : ${hiera_hash}":}
}

include test_hash
```

Next call puppet script `puppet apply test_hash.pp` 
In result:

> Notice:  normal: {"abc1"=>{"value"=>"apps"}, "abc2"=>{"value"=>"apps"}}
>
> Notice:  hiera : {"abc1"=>{"value"=>"apps"}, "abc3"=>{"value"=>"comm"}, "abc2"=>{"value"=>"apps"}}}

**UPDATE2:**
You can also consider using  [merge](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/stdlib#merge) function from stdlib. But probably to use it you will have to change a bit your architecture e.g:

In common define `common` values, in `node/%{::fqdn}` define node specific values, and than use it as in example:

```
$common_hash = hiera('something_from_common')
$node_hash   = hiera('something_from_fqdn')
$merged_hash = merge($node_hash, $common_hash)
```

(Yes it is a bit ugly :))

Comment: I added `:merge_behavior:` deeper to hiera.yaml but the behavior it is the same, only run the first match. I the common.yaml file there are the user1 and in the node/%{::fqdn}.yaml file there are the user2. if node/%{::fqdn}.yaml exist, puppet only will create the user2 and I need to create user1 and user2

Comment: I think that in addition to setting the merge behavior, you will have to use `hiera_hash()` instead of plain `hiera()` in your manifest.

Comment: @Frayp Sorry for late response. I have updated my answer, please check if it helps.